# Different accuracy cross validation libsvm and sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, libsvm, cross-validation

I have a precomputed Gram matrix for a dataset created by a custom kernel.
The Gram matrix is stored in a libsvm format.

I want to compute the mean accuracy given by a 10-fold cross validation using a SVC classifier, with C=10.

Using libsvm from command line I do:

```
svm-train -t 4 -v 10 -c 10 gram.libsvm
```

and I recive this output

```
Cross Validation Accuracy = 79.0869%
```

Now, I want to replicate the same value in Python, using the sklearn library. I know that sklearn should be implemented over libsvm, so I'm expecting the same results.

In Python I have the following code:

```
#gram1 is the Gram matrix of my custom kernel and y are the labels

clf = svm.SVC(C=10,kernel='precomputed')
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, gram1, y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')

print scores.mean()
```

The result is

```
0.788786616898
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE 1.0**
I continue to have different cv accuracy values between sklearn and libsvm. I checked the data is the same between both version. I decided to put online my data. This is the [gram matrix](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47524155/gram.mtx), this is the [gram matrix in libsvm format](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47524155/gram.libsvm) and these are the [labels](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/47524155/labels.target).

On libsvm I'm running this command:

```
svm-train -t 4 -v 10 -c 10 gram.libsvm
```

And I get this output:

```
Cross Validation Accuracy = 79.2553%
```

On Python sklearn I'm running the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file
yl=load_target("labels.target",'file')
gram1=np.loadtxt("gram.mtx")
print gram1.mean()
x, y = load_svmlight_file("gram.libsvm")
print x.shape
print x[0,:]
x=x.todense()[:,1:]
print np.array_equal(gram1,x)

print gram1[0,:]

print np.array_equal(y, yl)

clf = svm.SVC(C=10,kernel='precomputed')

scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, gram1, y, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))
print scores.mean()
```

and I get 0.788538011696 of accuracy.

This is a little gap compared to others I get, sometimes I get 8 points of gap between the results of libsvm and sklearn.

I'm using version 0.16 of sklearn and libsvm-tools 3.12-1.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to fix? Why do you expect that the two cross-validation implementation do exactly the same data splits?

Comment: I thought sklearn CV were just a binding to libsvm, ans I need the same CV of libsvm. Moreover, in some datasets I have a large gap between the accuracy score given by sklearn and libsvm

Comment: The cross-validation is done in scikit-learn, it is not using the libSVM cross-validation. There should never be any difference between libSVM results and scikit-learn results on the same data.

Comment: I updated the post with the code to check the different values. I checked that the data is the same between libsvm and sklearn, but I still have different values.